# Pandas how to delete alternate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with duplicate ids. Below is my dataframe

```
id  nbr  type  count 
7   21   High     4  
7   21   Low      6    
8   39   High     2    
8   39   Low      3    
9   13   High     5    
9   13   Low      7
```

How to delete only the rows having the type `Low`

Answer (score 33):

You can also just slice your df using [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#selection-by-position):

```
df.iloc[::2]
```

This will step every 2 rows

Answer (score 5):

You can try this way :

```
df = df[df.type != "Low"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('nbr')
print(df)

   id  nbr  type  count
0   7   21  High      4
2   8   39  High      2
4   9   13  High      5
```

You can also do:

```
df.drop_duplicates('nbr', inplace=True)
```

That way you don't have to reassign it.